# What does "PersonBean myBean =(PersonBean)request.getAttribute("myBean");" mean in Java?

Tags: java

I am learning java and came accross this code from an example.

```
PersonBean myBean =(PersonBean)request.getAttribute("myBean");
if(myBean=null)
{
  myBean = new PersonBean();
  request.setAttribute("myBean",myBean);
}
```

Here what does `PersonBean myBean =(PersonBean)request.getAttribute("myBean");` is doing? I mean in the if statement there already is a statement that constructs an object of this class . But what is the purpose of the first line here? Can anyone break it down for me ?

Comment: It is attempting to get a reference to a PersonBean object that is cached in a request object.  If one is not found, it creates a new one, and caches it in the request.

Comment: It's simply trying to get the object from the request.  If it's null, then create a new one and set it in the request.  The first line casts to PersonBean because request.getAttribute(String name) returns an Object.

Comment: OK i was asking with overall reference to an object . Like ..........SomeClass obj=(SomeClass)anyObj.method(blah blah); What this line is doing in terms of any class and any object? Is there a term for it ?

Comment: The only time i saw this kind of concept was during learning type-casting.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the "myBean" attribute from the request object (which contains all the incoming objects) and then casts it as PersonBean. If this is not successful then it creates a new PersonBean object with name "myBean" and sets the "myBean" object in the request.